# ASP.NET MVC5 Change Language using Route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, currentculture, uiculture

I'm new using MVC5 and I try to do a website with different language.
So far I do some configuration and when I click a different language it changes the url but it doesn't change the text in view.
Here is my code if anyone have idea:

In App_Data folder I have 2 files: CultureConstraint and CultureFilter

```
public class CultureFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
private readonly string defaultCulture;

public CultureFilter(string defaultCulture)
{
    this.defaultCulture = defaultCulture;
}

public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var values = filterContext.RouteData.Values;

    string culture = (string)values["culture"] ?? this.defaultCulture;

    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(culture);

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
}
}


public class CultureConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
private readonly string defaultCulture;
private readonly string pattern;

public CultureConstraint(string defaultCulture, string pattern)
{
    this.defaultCulture = defaultCulture;
    this.pattern = pattern;
}

public bool Match(
    HttpContextBase httpContext,
    Route route,
    string parameterName,
    RouteValueDictionary values,
    RouteDirection routeDirection)
{
    if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.UrlGeneration &&
        this.defaultCulture.Equals(values[parameterName]))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch((string)values[parameterName], "^" + pattern + "$");
    }
}
}
```

In RouteConfig I add:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultWithCulture",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
constraints: new { culture = new CultureConstraint(defaultCulture: "en", pattern: "[a-z]{2}") }
);
```

In filterConfig:

```
filters.Add(new CultureFilter(defaultCulture: "en"));
```

In the _Layout View Page:

```
@using Test.App_LocalResources;
@{
  var routeValues = this.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
  var controller = routeValues["controller"] as string;
  var action = routeValues["action"] as string;
}

   <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Russia", @action, @controller, new { culture = "ru" }, new { rel = "alternate", hreflang = "ru" })</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("English", @action, @controller, new { culture = "en" }, new { rel = "alternate", hreflang = "en" })</li>
        </ul>
        <div style="background: silver">
            @GlobalRes.Money:  <br />
            @GlobalRes.DateAndTime: <br />
        </div>
```

And Also in the View Page:

```
@using Test.App_LocalResources;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = GlobalRes.Title;
}
```

I put the language file in App_LocalResources with the name Global.resx and Global.ru.resx.

So Title, Money and DateTime always get the english text never the russia one.
Did I miss anything?

Comment: You can use resource files for multi languages https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw69ke6f.aspx

Comment: When I tried do that I save url that help me I sure that help you

[1](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx)

[2](http://www.chambaud.com/2013/02/27/localization-in-asp-net-mvc-4/)

[3](http://kaynzhang.blogspot.co.il/2013/11/5.html)

[4](http://kaynzhang.blogspot.co.il/2013/11/qw2.html)

[5](http://www.ryadel.com/en/setup-a-multi-language-website-using-asp-net-mvc/)